# Scalar to the power vector

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

I have a formula that contains $\log (I + e^{X})$ term where $X$ is an $N$ dimensional vector ($x_0, x_1, ..., x_{N-1}$) and $I$ is the unity vector. I don't know how the exponentiation and log operations are defined in the case of vector. How to express this formula in terms of individual components of $X$?

Is $$e^X = [e^{x_0},e^{x_1},...,e^{x_{n-1}}]$$

and

$$\log(V) = [\log(v_0), \log(v_1), ..., \log(v_{N-1})]$$

?

Comment: Are you sure that $I$ (and $X$) is not a matrix? That case has a well established definition. If you indeed mean, as you say, that $X$ is a vector then this is really bad notation - its not obvious at all how to interpret it (and there is no well established definition). That being said: if I was forced to make such a definition then your suggestion is what seems most natural.

Comment: @Winther yes, X and I are vectors. Let me try to cite original equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is a matrix, you can use the Taylor formula: for example, $$\exp(A)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{A^k}{k!}$$ If $A$ is a $N$ dimensional vector you have: $f(A)=\left[f(A_1),f(A_2,...f(A_N)\right]$

Comment: What if it's a matrix with Nx1 size? In short what is the difference between Nx1 matrix and N dim vector?

Comment: hint:$[v_1,v_2,v_3]^k=[v_1^k,v_2^k,v_3^k]$. So is the same for matrices

Answer (score 2):

Almost all of the time, if you don't know what $e^X$ means in some context, it means the usual power series:

$$e^X = 1 + X + \frac{X^2}{2} + \ldots$$

Of course, this relies on a notion of a "product" of two vectors, and it's not automatically clear what that means. The obvious choice is the geometric product, but you'd know if it was that.

Your use of the phrase "identity vector" is suggestive. There is no such thing, so you may have meant something other than "vector". I think you might be referring to operators, i.e. matrices.

**Edit**

It turns out that all is well, and these are all scalars. The actual equation is of the form:

$$\mathbf{y} = C \log ( 1 + e^{C^{-1} \mathbf{x}} )$$

...where $C$ is a discrete Fourier transform. (It's actually in cepstral space rather than the usual frequency space, but anyone playing along at home can ignore this detail.)

The inverse DFT transforms the vector of frequency components back into a continuous function, and it is this function which goes through $\exp$ and $\log$. At the final step, the manipulated continuous function is re-transformed back into a frequency vector.

Did that make sense?

Comment: I checked again, it was a typo, I is a unity vector, not identity.

Comment: Then I'm confused. Can you provide a little more context?

Comment: Please see equation 2 here `oa.ee.tsinghua.edu.cn/~ouzhijian/pdf/htl06.pdf` Neglect the C transform.

Comment: No, don't neglect the $C$ transform! That's the part that you're missing!

Comment: `vector of frequency components back into a continuous function` I thought output of the transform is another vector. Isn't that so?

Comment: If you take a vector of frequency components and IDFT it, you get a continuous function. So that's what it is mathematically. From an implementation point of view, when you're implementing this in real software on real hardware, you probably sample the continuous function for ease of manipulation, and hence you'd likely implement it using a vector or array or whatever abstraction your programming language provides. It *is* a continuous function, but you might *represent* it as a vector.